# Justifying user input string into lines of equal length

Tags: c++

So, full disclosure, I have just started learning C++ and this IS part of an assignment. I'm not looking for an answer, just a some guidance.

I'm looking to justify some text in the form of a string into lines of equal length. Both the text and line length are user-input.

What I've got so far is the code below. It works just fine to do the task at hand. I've thrown a bunch of text at it and it's always output the correct formatting for it. However, I am feeling as though I'm going at it the wrong way - the code feels clunky, as if I was forcing it to do something it wasn't designed to do (if you know what I mean).

Should I be looking (or is there) a more elegant way to do what I'm trying to do. I've considered setting up a 2D array of size [width][#lines] so that I can output it line by line. Would that be a preferable way to do things? Is there some sort of "Best Practice" when it comes to this stuff?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string randtext;
string output;
int width;

// User input text string.
cout << "Enter a Random String of Text: " << endl;
getline(cin, randtext);
// User input line width.
cout << "Enter justification Width" << endl;
cin >> width;

int length = randtext.length();

int i = 0;
// This bit parses through the string.
while (i <= length)
{
    // This bit creates lines of length = width.
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
    {
        if (i + j > length) { break; }
        char letter = randtext[i+j];
        output += letter;
    }

    // This bit outputs the lines and then clears everything.
    cout << output << endl;
    output.clear();
    i += width;

}

cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone stumbles onto this in the future looking for an answer to a similar question, I ended up scrapping my previous code and used SUBSTR (as suggested by @cbranch)to chop up the text and fed it into a VECTOR as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

string input = "The quick brown fox, jumps over the. Lazy dog. There is, no cow. LEVEL";
int width = 20;
int length = input.size();
int j = 0;

vector<string> input_vector (0);

// For loop that chops up the input using input.substr() and feeds it into a vector that re-sizes as needed.
for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=width)
{
    // Dynamic vector resizing as needed.
    input_vector.resize(j + 1);

    string input_sub = input.substr(i, width);

    input_vector[j] = input_sub;
    j++;

}

int size_vector = input_vector.size();

// For loop that outputs the chopped out lines as elements of the vector.
for (int k = 0; k < size_vector; ++k)
{
    cout << input_vector[k] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has a bug: array indices are 0-based, meaning that `0` to `length - 1` are valid, but `length` is not a valid index.  If your goal is to split a string into fixed-sized chunks without any other conditions or constraints, you might consider using `string::substr()`.  This would reduce the amount of code, and make things clearer.

But I'm wondering whether fixed-sized chunks is actually your goal?  When I hear "justified" text, I think about text that has been word wrapped (i.e., split on word boundaries) and then spaces inserted so that the left and right edges of each line are aligned.  Example:

`The quick red fox jumped over the two lazy dogs.`

Justified using 14-character line width:

```
The quick  red
fox     jumped
over  the  two
lazy dogs.
```

Comment: The end goal is indeed to fully justify the text (both left and right), and I am working on that. I was just worried that I was going down a wrong path when splitting the text into lines.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as far as I know there are no best practices. However I would suggest keeping it as simple as possible. I've used a similar approach to what you have done however I have instead inserted a new line character every `width` interval to the `randtext` string and then printed that. This dramatically reduces the code size and improves readability. I have tested this against your code and the output is exactly the same. The code is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string randtext;
    int width;

    // User input text string.
    cout << "Enter a Random String of Text: " << endl;
    getline(cin, randtext);
    // User input line width.
    cout << "Enter justification Width" << endl;
    cin >> width;

    // Insert a newline character every nth character given that n = width
    for (size_t i = 0; i < randtext.length(); i+=width+1)
    {
        randtext.insert(i,"\n");
    }
    cout << randtext << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea. It definitely makes it easier to read through. Even removes the need for nested loops.

Comment: @Roverandom Yeah to be honest I couldn't work out how your nested loops work. I just compiled your code worked out what it did and simplified the proccess. :)